# How do I map received data before they get displayed?

Tags: angular, typescript, syncfusion

I wonder how to solve the following problem:

I am using Syncfusion for the gridlayout. I store received data external file named datasource.ts as mentioned in the documentation:

```
//component.ts
//getting data from server

     ngOnInit() {

       this.user.someFunction().subscribe(data => {
       this.datasource.data = data;

        }) 
       }
```

in my html-file I use that data to build a grid:

```
   <ej-grid id="Grid" #grid [dataSource]="datasource.data" allowPaging="true" 
    allowFiltering="true" 
    selectionType="single" allowSelection="true"
    [selectionSettings]="selectionMode" (rowSelected)="rowSelected($event)"  
    (recordDoubleClick)="Doubleclick($event)">
      <e-columns>
          <e-column field="digit" headerText="Digits"></e-column>
      </e-columns>
  </ej-grid>
```

So far so good. 
I want to map the digits I receive (of couse of type number) and replace it with related strings, eg.:

1 - "One",
2- "Two",

such that strings are displayed instead of the received digits, but it does not seem to word.
I have to change something in my call:

```
// in service

  someFunction(): Observable<Data[]>{

     return this.http.get<Data[]>(url).pipe(
     map((data: any[]) => data.map(order => this.orderadapter.adapt(data)
     )));
  }
```

but I do not know how to place another mapping there.
Could anyone help with some (dummy) code? Maybe there are other solutions to my problem?

Comment: post  your sample data here

Comment: It is an array of objects, in this case we assume these objects just have the property digit: ```datasource.data = [ {digit: value}, ...]```, or do you want to see how it looks like in the console?

Comment: so here digit will be 1-9 right?

Comment: @jitender It does not matter, I just want to understand how it works :). An example with only 2 digits would also be enough :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a simple excample with switch case on the digits: 1, 2

```
this.user.someFunction().subscribe(data => {
    this.datasource.data = data.map(digit => this.transform(digit));
}) 

transform(digit: number): string {
    switch (digit) {
        case 1: return 'One';
            break;
        case 2: return 'Two';
            break;
        default: return 'Not one or two';
    }
}
```

Here is the [map docu](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

> Edit: Map when you want to keep your object and just want to transform some attributes

```
this.user.someFunction().subscribe(data => {
    this.datasource.data = data.map(data => data.digit = this.transform(data.digit));
})

...
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. If I may ask you something, if I expand the object with another property like ```Data {digit: value,  anotherProp: value}```How can I get it to map only the values of the digits? Because now the digit in you code represents the whole Object Data

Comment: Try `data.map(data=> this.transform(data.digit));`. Bute care! This will not return `{digit: value, anotherProp: value}`, instead the map will return a string Array

Comment: Yes, I did that, but the problem is that I store an array of strings (string[]) instead of the whole object with all properties... The problem is that with syncfusion I only can use the datasource variable.

Comment: Thank you for editing :), but I still get the error ```Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'Order[]'.
  Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Order'.```

Comment: This just might be a conversion error. Try to `console.log` one dataset and look if it looks ok, when it does, just cast the object to `Order` and it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

you can try creating a function to convert digit to word like

```
inWords (num) {
var a = ['','one ','two ','three ','four ', 'five ','six ','seven ','eight ','nine ','ten ','eleven ','twelve ','thirteen ','fourteen ','fifteen ','sixteen ','seventeen ','eighteen ','nineteen '];
var b = ['', '', 'twenty','thirty','forty','fifty', 'sixty','seventy','eighty','ninety'];

    if ((num = num.toString()).length > 9) return 'overflow';
    n = ('000000000' + num).substr(-9).match(/^(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{1})(\d{2})$/);
    if (!n) return; var str = '';
    str += (n[1] != 0) ? (a[Number(n[1])] || b[n[1][0]] + ' ' + a[n[1][1]]) + 'crore ' : '';
    str += (n[2] != 0) ? (a[Number(n[2])] || b[n[2][0]] + ' ' + a[n[2][1]]) + 'lakh ' : '';
    str += (n[3] != 0) ? (a[Number(n[3])] || b[n[3][0]] + ' ' + a[n[3][1]]) + 'thousand ' : '';
    str += (n[4] != 0) ? (a[Number(n[4])] || b[n[4][0]] + ' ' + a[n[4][1]]) + 'hundred ' : '';
    str += (n[5] != 0) ? ((str != '') ? 'and ' : '') + (a[Number(n[5])] || b[n[5][0]] + ' ' + a[n[5][1]]) + 'only ' : '';
    return str;
}
```

and then

```
return this.http.get<Data[]>(url).pipe(
     map((data: any[]) => {
     return data.map(d=>{
         return {
             this.inWords(yourdigitkey)//
          }
        })
       }
     )))
```

Comment: Thank you for the answere. I will try it!